# Best way to make a WYSIWYG in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, forms, wysiwyg

I have a client that wants a WYSIWYG form that behaves like MS word.  It will have some section labels in it, with users expected to enter notes for each section, and it needs a place holder for a chart.  The trick is that the user needs to know where page breaks are going to fall when printed.  The customer agrees to fixed size paper with fixed sized margins.  How should I approach this challenge?  Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Here is an example:

Section 1: Explain Idea Here
    { As user types in this section, the space between this section and the next section expands, but I as the user can't delete the lines that say Section 1 or 2, or the place holder for the chart.  However if I type a lot of text, I need to display where the page breaks are with a dashed line or something, so the user can make sure the content enters appears on the desired page.  If I type a lot here for example, section 2 will get pushed onto the next page}

Section 2: State why this is a Good Idea

[ PLACE HOLDER FOR CHART
.
.
.
]

Section 3: Additional Remarks:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article on this topic:
http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/creating-what-you-see-is-what-you-get-editor-wysiwyg-with-as3-flex-tutorial

hope it helps ;)